# CD is height of right-angled triangle ABC, M and N are midpoints of CD and BD: prove AM⊥CN

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was having some troubles proving this:
CD is the height that corresponds to the hypotenuse of right-angled triangle ABC. If M and N are midpoints of CD and BD, prove that AM is perpendicular to CN.
Here's the illustration (by me): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWLZl.jpg

Sorry for my English. Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: Can be easily proved using vectors. Denote $\vec{CA}=\vec{a}, \vec{CB}=\vec{b}, \vec{CD}=\vec{c}$ and use dot products.

Comment: That sounds interesting, but I think I'll stick to other methods because of my limited knowledge on vectors. For curiosity's sake, could anyone just tell me roughly what to do using that method (I'll figure out why). Feel free to use answer instead of comment. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Now when I've read my comment, it sounded wrong and I can't edit it. Of course explanation/reference would be great, but only thing I know about dot vector are the formulas (how to calculate it), so I suppose it'd be tiring to have to explain everything. So far, I've learnt best from examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After denoting the vectors like I did, we have that $\vec{AD}=\vec{c}-\vec{a}, \vec{DB}=\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. Dot product property: $(AB\perp CD\iff \vec{AB}\cdot \vec{CD}=0)$. Using this and various other dot product properties like distributive, commutative properties we eventually have $\vec{a}\vec{c}=\vec{c}^2$, $\vec{a}\vec{b}=0$, $\vec{b}\vec{c}=\vec{c}^2$. We want to prove that $\vec{AM}\perp \vec{CN}\iff \vec{AM}\cdot\vec{CN}=0$. We know that $\vec{AM}=\frac{\vec{c}-\vec{a}-\vec{a}}{2}=\frac{\vec{c}-2\vec{a}}{2}$. $\vec{CN}=\frac{\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show $\angle MAD=\angle NCD$, which means two right triangles 
$ADM$ and $CDN$ are similar. This can be proved from $AD/DM=CD/DN$, which follows from $AD/CD=CD/BD$.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be analytic geometry (but I am not sure it is the simplest):
endow $\mathbb{R^2}$ with a coordinate system where
$C=(0,0)$, $A=(0,a)$, $B=(b,0)$. The line $L(A,B)$ ($L(P,Q)$ is the line through $P$ and $Q$) is $y=-\frac{a}{b}x+a$, the line $L(C,D)$ is $y=\frac{b}{a}x$, then solve the coordinates of $D,M,N$ write the equation of lines $L(C,N)$ and $L(A,M)$, and check orthogonality...